# $\lim_{n \to \infty} (u_{n+1}-u_n)$ does not converge then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$ does not converge

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers

Prove that if $\lim_{n \to \infty} (u_{n+1}-u_n)$ does not converge then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$ does not converge.

**My try**-
Contrapositive statement - If $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n$ converges then $\lim_{n \to \infty} (u_{n+1}-u_n)$ converges.

Let , $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n=L$

Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} u_{n+1}=L$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} (u_{n+1}-u_n)=L-L=0$

Is the proof correct? Any other proof is also desirable.

Comment: Do not edit your question to completely change its meaning.  Doing so creates a moving target for potential answerers.  If you get an answer in the comments, consider self-answering the question using those comments.  Or consider deleting the question if you don't think that the answer in the comments will be of much use to future readers.  If a new question arises use the "Ask Question" button to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a bit of terminology: a limit does ***not*** converge. Sequences converge, while limits (may) exist and equal something. Another thing: please be sure to define the environment where you are working. What is $u_n$? A sequence of real numbers? A sequence of functions? A sequence with values in which space?

Suppose we are talking about sequences of real numbers. If the sequence converges, then it is a cauchy sequence, meaning that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exist a $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n,m > N$ we have $ |u_{n+1} - u_n| < \varepsilon$.

Now define the following: $a_n := u_{n+1} - u_n$. You easily see that $a_n$ converges by definition of cauchy sequence.